# Invalid key in stanza in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I'm getting the following error while starting splunk

```
Invalid key in stanza [lmpool:auto_generated_pool_free] in /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/server.conf, line 25: defaultGroup  (value:  splunkssl).
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing someone has added `defaultGroup = splunkssl` to your server.conf file. That looks like it should actually be in the outputs.conf file. Check the Splunk docs for both those files and confirm, but I think you'll need to either remove that line or move it to outputs